# MongoDb: aggregate is omiting documents in the final result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using aggregate to rename a property in the document. Aggregation is working that it renames the property as needed but it is not returning all the documents from original collection.

```
db.packs.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      apps: {
        $map: {
          input: "$apps",
          as: "app",
          in: {
            _id: "$$app._id",
            did: "$$app.did",
            name: "$$app.name",
            codes: "$$app.regions"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project:{
      "apps.regions":0
    }
  },
  {
    $out:"updatedpacks"
  }
])
```

Here `packs` collection has 141 documemnts in it but the aggregated results `updatedpacks` collection has only 46 documents in it. I am trying to understand why it ommitted documents

Comment: try to run: `db.updatedpacks.countDocuments({})`. Sometimes `.count` doesn't return real nº of documents

Comment: You don't need this stage `{
    $project:{
      "apps.regions":0
    }
  }` How are you checking for count ?

Comment: I am using studio 3T to execute the query and it added this new collection in database and showing it has 46 documents in the collection